# Let G and H be two graphs. Prove that $\chi '(G \cup H) \leq \chi ' (G) + \chi ' (H)$.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, algebraic-graph-theory

Let G and H be two graphs (not necessarily edge disjoint). Prove that $\chi '(G \cup H) \leq \chi ' (G) + \chi ' (H)$.

Here $\chi '$ represents the edge chromatic number. Not sure where to start with this really. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think, that this is false.

Comment: I know it's false for normal chromatic number, but seems it's true for edge chromatic number as I've been asked to prove it

Comment: Consider a graph with 4 vertices {1,2,3,4} and 5 edges {(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,4),(3,4)}. The subgraphs G = {1,2} and H = {3,4} have edge chromatic number 1, while in an edge coloring of the whole graph (1,2),(1,3),(1,4) must have distinct colors.

Comment: The union of your subgraphs G and H would not be the graph you mentioned. It's unable to have edges (1,4), (1,3) and (2,4) since vertices 3 and 4 don't exist in G and similarly with H. It's hard to word but I don't think that works as a counterexample.

Comment: What's wrong with using the colorings for $G$ and $H$ with disjoint colors, and say, the common edges receive their color from $G$?